# finding the modulus of time delta in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the modulus of two time delta columns in Pandas. My data frame looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d={'date':(['01/01/2018','05/02/2018','01/01/2018','05/01/2018']),\
'fct date':(['01/06/2019','01/06/2019','01/06/2019','01/06/2019']),\
'tenor':[1,2,3,4]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['fct date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fct date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')


df['tenor']=pd.to_timedelta(df['tenor'],unit="d")
df
```

when I try to apply the modulus function, I get a unsupported operand timedeltaindex error. Any idea why this is throwing an error ?

```
a=(df['date']-df['fct date'])%df['tenor']
```

Comment: Your sample code actually works for me without an error. You could maybe try `(df['date'] - df['fct date']).dt.days % df['tenor'].dt.days` ...?

Comment: What is your pandas version? In pandas 0.24.2 it working nice.

Comment: the pandas version i am using is :0.23.4

Comment: looks like this is an issue with Pandas version 0.23.4. After I upgraded to 0.24.2, I didn't get the error